# hide or non-clickable row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hide

when any user upload document and then this document goes for approval to supervsior so when supervsior approve/reject this document then i want this specific row non-clickable or i want to hide that row 
picture
[pic](http://i57.tinypic.com/2jeo4ub.png)

and here the code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                string empId = string.Empty;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    mySQLconnection.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Repeater2.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
                        HiddenField DocId = ((HiddenField)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocId"));

                        //Label DocId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocId"));

                        //Label Label2 = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("Label2"));
                        //if (Label2.Text.ToString() != "")
                        //{
                        //    string emailId = Label2.Text.ToString();
                        //}



                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32((DocId.Value));


                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = (Session["Login2"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DesigID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (Session["UserDesignationID"]);


                        string DocName = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocName")).Text;
                        string emailId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("YourEamil")).Text;
                        DropDownList dropdownvalue = ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
                        string approver = Session["Login2"] != null ? Session["Login2"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                        string Designationn = Session["UserDesignationID"] != null ? Session["UserDesignationID"].ToString() : string.Empty;

                        string docname = String.Empty;
                        string emailID = String.Empty;
                        string dropdownvalues = String.Empty;





                        if (Session["Login2"] != null)
                        {
                            approver = Session["Login2"].ToString();
                        }
                        if (Session["UserDesignationID"] != null)
                        {
                            Designationn = Session["UserDesignationID"].ToString();
                        }

                        if (DocName.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            docname = DocName.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            docname = "Unavailable";
                        }
                        if (emailId.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            emailID = emailId.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            emailID = "Unavailable";
                        }

                        if (dropdownvalue.SelectedItem.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            dropdownvalues = dropdownvalue.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dropdownvalues = "Unavailable";
                        }

                        //SendEmailUsingGmail(docname.ToString(), dropdownvalue.ToString(), emailId.ToString());
                        //SendEmailUsingGmail(DocName.ToString(), emailId.ToString(), dropdownvalue.ToString());
                        SendEmailUsingGmail(DocName, emailId, dropdownvalues, approver, Designationn);


                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Successz.Text = "Documents Approve and Email Successfully Send To Users";






                        //UPDATE APPPROVEID IN DOCUMENTINFO TABLE
                        //DMSLIB.Doc myDoc = new DMSLIB.Doc();
                        //myDoc.MarkDocAs(Convert.ToInt16(DocId.Text), Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue));

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Supvisor.Text = "Error";
                }
                if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    mySQLconnection.Close();
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                Supvisor.Text = "Already Approved";


            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just exclude the row in sql? I.e don't bring back any rows from your query you don't want to display.

Comment: no... obviously when user upload document then this document goes for approval to supervsior then when this supervsior approve/reject document then once he do action then i want this row hide or non-clickable and also when new document comes and again supervsior approve/reejct this document then previous data not goes to table beacuse data is already save in table